# I'm new to android studio and I do not understand why it's getting this way

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The app opens normal in the emulator but when I open the activity it stays so I can not understand why I did not do anything different

**In the emulator:**
[image: emulator]

**In the activity:**
[image: activity]

Comment: have you tried cleaning and re-building the project ?

Comment: Close the project and reopen?

Comment: @Talisoon that will also probably work. But I think the cleaning and rebuilding should work. 1. Build > Clean Project 2. Build > Rebuild Project 3. Run the app

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite frequent. You need to rebuild the project. 
Go to Build > Rebuild Project, and once the rebuilding process is complete, the errors should go away.